# Can anyone explain that how can I use mathematical equation

Tags: latex, mathjax

Can anyone explain that how can I use mathematical equation in wordpress website.

Like  code and how to write the equation etc. many more

---

Recently I published a mathematical code on my website - https://hindimaihelper.com/sample/ but its not working.

I want like that - https://wbshiksha.com/class-10-mathematics-koshe-dekhi-6-2/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

#### WordPress supports latex.

You can simply write

```
$latex <your formula>$
```

For example, if you would like to write $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ you can write

```
$latex \int_a^b f(x)dx$
```

For more information about for example changing background color, see the [documentation](https://wordpress.com/support/latex/).

---

#### Alterantively, you may use MathJax.

In my case, the previous strategy did not work and I do not understand why. I installed the MathJax Plug-in, I activated it following the procedure depicted [here in this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/15612/223732) and everything went fine.